# How to disable logging of verbose unuseful logs of IIS in Azure

Tags: iis, logging, azure

I have noticed that IIS of Azure Web-Roles is generating a lot of logs, most indicating access of web-spiders.
They are stored in the "wad-iis-logfiles" blob container.

What is the easiest way of disabling these kind verbose unuseful logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Azure is simply transferring the IIS logs to blob storage, so whatever's in them is going to get transferred. If you don't want those logs at all, just change your Diagnostics config. If you do want IIS logs but somehow want to filter out these requests, I think you'll have to do that on the IIS side.

(I'm not clear on which of those things you want to do.)

Answer (score 1):

not a direct answer to your question but 'The David Aiken' has a nice blog post and script how to handle these at a deployment level...

How To Clean up old Windows Azure diagnostics

http://www.davidaiken.com/2011/10/26/how-to-clean-up-old-windows-azure-diagnostics/

I'm interested to know how to do it in Azure/IIS (start-up task against IIS?)

Update you need to add WaIISHost.exe.config file like the diagnostics.wadcfg*****

Comment: There could be something in the diagnostics.wadcfg file on IIS, I haven't used it to that granular level but...